# Heroku compilation arguments

Tags: java, compilation, heroku

I'm facing problems with the UTF-8 encoding on Heroku. I need to pass the argument `-encoding UTF-8` to `javac` while compiling.

How can I achieve it?

Seems like a stupid and simple question but couldn't find any solution online.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Maven, you can pass compiler arguments using the maven-compiler-plugin like this:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <compilerArgument>-encoding UTF-8</compilerArgument>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

(I didn't actually test this snippet). Doc is here:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html

Comment: I think you can set this with:

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding

Comment: Did the answers in this other question you posted not work out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808224/heroku-replacing-utf-8-bytes-with-0xef-0xbf-0xbd

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @JesperJ.. As you already found out, this is the solution I tried but apparently it's not working. After asking that question, I thought to post another question just about the compliation in Heroku. Apparently it turns out I was doing in the correct way. If the compilation arguments are ok, I really don't know how to fix that problem... To be sure that Heroku is using the specified `javac` arguments, is there anyway to get the compilation log in Heroku? Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem. @JesperJ. your solution is correct, the problem I had was due to AspectJ, when you want to use it you have to specify the UTF-8 encoding in the configuration... Thank you!